# padding zeros to binary numbers using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, binary, printf

How to pad zero to binary numbers using shell script.

binary.txt

```
1010011100010001010111001101111
0
10110000000101000000000000001
10100000011
1000000100
1111111111111111
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
```

when i do the following

```
printf "%032s\n" $(<binary.txt)
```

I get a white space.

```
  1010011100010001010111001101111
                                0
    10110000000101000000000000001
                      10100000011
                       1000000100
                 1111111111111111
 11111111111111110000000000000000
 11111111111111110000000000000000
 11111111111111110000000000000000
```

But I need zero's appended. Any input is appreciated.
thanks,

**Updated:**

binary.txt is my input file and has the following contents.

```
1010011100010001010111001101111
0
10110000000101000000000000001
10100000011
1000000100
1111111111111111
11111111111111110000000000000000
11111111111111110000000000000000
```

while running the following command in the command line it works fine.

```
   printf "%032s\n" $(<binary.txt) | tr ' ' '0' >> t1.mif
```

But when i try to do the same using a script below , it gives me wrong values. Any suggestions.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=binary.txt
while read line;do
    printf "%032s\n" $line | tr ' ' '0' >> t1.mif
done < $FILE
```

thanks

Comment: Which platform are you running on? I just tried `printf "%032s\n" "110011" "001100"` on Mac OS X and got what you'd wanted.

Comment: I am running it on linux platform. for some reason i don't see the zeros. Julienc answers works for me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tr` to replace the spaces you get with zeroes:

```
printf "%032s\n" $(<binary.txt) | tr ' ' '0'
```

Answer (score 3):

julienc's answer using `tr` is right, and the best portable solution, but I wanted to highlight that you hit an interesting difference between BSD and GNU implementations of printf.

For [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&sektion=3):

```
 `0' (zero)   Zero padding.  For all conversions except n, the converted value is
              padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks.
```

For [GNU C in Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

```
 0            The value should be zero padded.  For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A,
              e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the converted value is
              padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks.
```

Thus, your code will probably work in BSD implementations such as Mac OS X, but for portability you should use the above `tr` solution.

Note that switching to `%d` or `%s` is also out for the sake of overflow:

```
printf "%032d\n" "101010101010101010101010101010"
-bash: printf: warning: 101010101010101010101010101010: Result too large
00000000000009223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `printf` does not support padding of strings - except with wide spaces. You can use the following awk script as an alternative.

```
awk '{for(i=length($0);i<32;i++){$0="0"$0}print}' bin.txt
```

Comment: +1: Right OP could use `%d` or `%.f` but then the numbers would go out of range.

Comment: @jaypal yes, unfortunately they are getting "out of range".